# Can Reputation be used or viewed as Currency?

Tags: discussion

Can Reputation be viewed as Currency and Wealth in any sense?

For example, with more reputation, I can create more bounties.
As I accumulate my reputation wealth, I accumulate badges, and more privileges.  Akin to becoming a member of an elite-only club (must have this much worth to be a member).

But then, once I lose some reputation (due to bounties or due to downvotes), I can lose some or the privileges once available to me.

So in a sense, reputation is like money, and like wealth, and like the culture of exclusive clubs.  Are there things that oppose this view?

Comment: Anything exchanged in return for something else can be viewed as a currency. Whether that are gold coins from the 15th century, sea shells used by a tribe in the pacific ocean or women of the night rendering services. So yes, reputation can be viewed as a currency but since SE is the only institution that accepts it, its not exactly the most useful one. I'd rather have sea shells from the pacific tribe.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Between gold coins, sea shells, and women of the night, you chose the sea shells!?

Comment: Hi Dennis, Your question reminded me about sealand. they also have currency. http://www.sealandgov.org/

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you could view it that way, but unlike traditional currency, the usefulness of rep diminishes the more you have of it. Once you've unlocked all the site privileges, additional boosts in rep do virtually nothing for you.

Rep is just about creating thresholds. You need a bare minimum amount of rep before you can vote, which is mostly just a counter-measure against creating bots that game the site. So on and so forth with each privilege. It's really about making sure that a user has garnered a certain amount of trust and respectability before they are allowed to take certain actions, so I would say more than currency, rep should simply be viewed has the trust StackOverflow has in you, which is really what "reputation" is about anyways.

Comment: *"unlike traditional currency, the usefulness of rep diminishes the more you have of it"* - I'm not sure that *is* unlike traditional currency, see "diminishing marginal utility".

Comment: yes.. there is one issue.  Should I decide to ask a few good questions on which I decide to open up bounties, and I do that a few times, my rep will go down, thereby also taking the `SO trust` in me along with it.  So I may theoretically go back down to near-0 rep, appearing to have little trust put into me, even though in reality I will still be a trusted user.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Q&A site. Reputation doesn't limit you from these basic features it keeps people who are new from making trash in an already well established society.
"Elite" is subjective also. You can still answer questions and you can still create this rep wealth from nothing. No one can keep you from answering a question on this site.

Placing a high stakes bounty to get a question answered doesn't always necessarily get a question answered. It helps you get a more specific answer or generally more exposure. I think people are attracted not by the rep but by the question itself. Like... "Why does this question have such a HUGE bounty." *Click*

Think of a bounty this way perhaps. You get fifty rep and place it on a question that can't or hasn't been answered. No one has downvoted it they just don't know the answer. It's a decent question that doesn't have an answer yet. You got that rep from answering questions or what have you. Then what you're asking the community to do is "Hey I helped out a bunch of people. Get me an answer for my question. I made a good question here and did the research. I still don't have a solution. Please help."

Losing rep for a poorly constructed answer is more than fair. Although a lot of things are subjective. This site has made it to where the answer is a direct and very precise scalpel for the question. If it's not the precise scalpel it's trash because it does not answer the specific question therefore reputation in the community should be removed and with it privileges need to go also.

To answer the question.

Removing rights with the currency no longer makes it a currency it makes it and abstract number value for (for lack of a better word) reputation in a community. Withheld and controlled by the owner of the number value with the option of adding to the communities rep at no cost. But, thats just how I view it.